# Changing a Power Virtual Agent Global Variable in Bot Framework Composer

Tags: bot-framework-composer, power-virtual-agents

I would be hugely grateful if someone could please let me know how to change a Power Virtual Agent variable in Bot Framework Composer.

I set it like this

[image: PVA Setting of Variable]

I am trying to change it in Bot Framework Composer as follows:

[image: Trying to change variable in BFC]

Here is the error that I get:

[image: Error]

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are seeing this error is because you are setting "bye" value to the type that has only two values ("Nil" and "Hello").

To make this work, you should whether assign "Nil"/"Hello" values in Composer Or change the type of your variable to string (Identify: "User's entire response")